# Why can't I find this button element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open an internet radio station and automatically click the Play button using selenium, but I can't find the Play button element.

I am using the following python script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_fourfm")

playButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "p_audioui_playpause")))

browser.close()
```

The WebDriverWait times out because it cannot find the button element with ID 'p_audioui_playpause'
If I replace this call with a simple sleep statement to wait for 30 seconds to make very sure the web site loads, and use a simple find_element, it asserts not being able to find the button

```
playButton = browser.find_element(By.ID, "p_audioui_playpause")
```

In both cases I can clearly see the play button in the browser, and using the Chrome development tools I can find the button and ascertain it's ID as 'p_audioui_playpause'

Why can't selenium find that Play button?

Comment: _Why can't selenium find that Play button?_ Because it's inside an `<iframe>`, and Selenium has special handling for those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you want to manipulate is within an iframe.

The webdriver needs to switch to the iframe.

This is the code that you need :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_fourfm")

iframe = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(((By.ID, "smphtml5iframesmp-wrapper"))))
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe);

playButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "p_audioui_playpause")))

browser.close()
```